# surefire forkMode causes only last test to be recorded in TestSuite.txt

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2, fork, surefire

I have the following in my pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- exclude integration tests -->
                    <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
        <!-- Enable the following for Cassandra unit test 
             support --> 
        <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

when I execute 'mvn test', in the end I only get results in TEST-TestSuite.txt for the last test run.

I do want forking enabled because I'm testing some Cassandra interactions and I'd like to do intermittent database cleanup.

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)
Java version: 1.6.0_18
Java home: /usr/java/jdk-1.6.0_18/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.32-24-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

Comment: Could you try with version 2.4.3 of the surefire plugin?

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: I have tried with 2.4.3 - it does not seem to make a difference.  :-/

Comment: It appears that this is a bug in surefire: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-446

Answer (score 0):

So far, it appears that the Surefire/TestNG combination simply does not support this.  I switched to using JUnit for my tests/integration-tests and have received the functionality I wanted.  The biggest loss for me was losing the @Test(priority) annotation, but I've simply restructured my tests to account for that.